# Can anyone help me understand why im getting this runtime error with my leetcode problem? Longest Prefix

Tags: javascript, algorithm, logic

I'm practicing Leetcode problems for an upcoming interview, I'm doing the longest prefix
problem and when I run the code with preset I pass every test but when I submit the code to pass I get a runtime error. Here is the code I wrote below.

```
/**
 * @param {string[]} strs
 * @return {string}
 */
var longestCommonPrefix = function(strs) {
    let splitWords = [];
    let commonPrefix =[];
    strs.forEach((word,i) =>{
        splitWords[i] = word.split('');
    })
    if( splitWords !== undefined || splitWords.length > 0){
    for(i=0; i < splitWords[0].length; i ++){
        if(splitWords[0][i] ==  splitWords[1][i] &&  splitWords[0][i] == splitWords[2][i]){
        
        commonPrefix.push(splitWords[0][i])
            console.log(commonPrefix)
         }else{
           break;
         }
        }
       }
  return (commonPrefix === undefined || commonPrefix.length == 0 ? commonPrefix = "" : commonPrefix.join(''))
};
```

Here is the error I am getting when I submit:

```
Line 12 in solution.js
    for(i=0; i < splitWords[0].length; i ++){
                               ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    Line 12: Char 32 in solution.js (longestCommonPrefix)
    Line 33: Char 19 in solution.js (Object.<anonymous>)
    Line 16: Char 8 in runner.js (Object.runner)
    Line 24: Char 26 in solution.js (Object.<anonymous>)
    Line 1200: Char 30 in loader.js (Module._compile)
    Line 1220: Char 10 in loader.js (Object.Module._extensions..js)
    Line 1049: Char 32 in loader.js (Module.load)
    Line 937: Char 14 in loader.js (Function.Module._load)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
    Line 17: Char 47 in run_main_module.js
```

Again it does work/pass when I run it with the test, When I submit it the code fails. I'm not sure what input the algorithm is trying to put in as well but I think it's an empty array?

I know I can just look up the answer but I am trying to solve the problem completely without looking it up.

//"Last executed input []"

Comment: is a empty array. make a check of strs.length on front of function. if is 0 then return 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the constraints of the Leetcode problem, you can see that there is a possibility of an empty string in the `strs` array.

`0 <= strs[i].length <= 200`

For example you can have `Input: strs = ["","flow","flight"]`.

With the way you are looping over the `strs` array, splitting every string and adding them to the `splitWords` array will lead to the following result:

```js
0: []
1: (5) ["f", "l", "o", "w"]
2: (5) ["f", "l", "i", "g", "h", "t"]
```

Not checking for an empty string will lead to your for-loop trying to access the `length` of the first value of an empty array, which is undefined.

Comment: Thank you can you explain how this works? i don't understand constrains written like this "0 <= strs[i].length <= 200"

Comment: Hey! You would read the constraints as you would read code. `strs[i]` indicates "for every item in the array". `.length` added would mean "the length for every item in the array". To the left you will find the values must be greater than or equal to 0. To the right you will find the values must be less than or equal to 200. Put it all together and you get `the length for every item in the array can be greater than or equal to 0 and less than or equal to 200`

Answer (score 0):

- input params is `[]`, `splitWords` init value is `[]`,
- then `splitWords !== undefined` is true,
- `splitWords[0].length` mean `([])[0].length`, Obviously `([])[0]` is undefined.

Comment: Please clean up your answer as it is difficult to understand it.